# Android SimpleDateFormat is not parsing hours

Tags: android, simpledateformat

when parsing using SimpleDateFormat the milliseconds of date object is not correct

```
Date locally=new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm").parse("03:00");
```

the locally milliseconds is 3600000 but the true result must be 3*60*60*1000=10800000

Comment: Use "HH:mm" for the `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: same result when use "HH:mm"

Comment: Is there supposed to be a question here? Also the title and content of your 'question' are statements about separate problems

Comment: Do you happen to be in a time zone that is 2 hours ahead of UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a timezone-less information like "03:00" to a global type like `Date` is always timezone-relevant. In your case parsing uses the default timezone of your system which has obviously an extra offset of two hours so you get the local time reduced by two hours, resulting in an UTC-timestamp of 1970-01-01T01:00Z.

It seems you want to interprete the input as kind of duration. Although a `Date`-object is naturally NOT a duration you might slightly misuse the `Date`-type this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // interprete input in UTC (zero offset)
Date d = sdf.parse("03:00"); // timestamp equivalent to 1970-01-01T03:00Z
long durationInMillis = d.getTime(); // 10800000 ms relative to UNIX epoch
```